# Why does my `write` give UnicodeDecodeError on OSX but not Linux?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, scons

I have this code in a `scons` build file:

```
with io.open(target[0].get_path(), 'w', encoding="utf-8") as target_file:
            target_file.write( unicode("std::string {} = R\"~~~~({})~~~~\";").format(varName,content))
```

The `content` variable will contain non-ascii characters. On OSX I don't have a problem, but on Linux I get a `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte` error.

Oddly, if I use just `open` instead, remove the encoding, and drop the `unicode` bit the reverse happens: it works on Linux and not on OSX.

```
with open(target[0].get_path(), 'w') as target_file:
    target_file.write( "std::string {} = R\"~~~~({})~~~~\";".format(varName,content))
```

What is wrong and how do I fix it?

Versions:

- OSX Python: 2.7.10
- OSX Scons: 3.0.1
- Linux Python: 2.7.12
- Linux Scons: 2.4.1

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The question should be answerable without a full reproduction. It's a question about the appropriate use of Python and understanding what is going wrong.

Comment: we can't provide a for-sure answer without a [mcve] with this encoding stuff. it's not so difficult. Just assign `contents` and varname to some value that triggers the error and you're done. It's not asking a lot, help us help you

Comment: I don't need a for sure answer. I'm looking for anybody that can indicate the potential reasons, like a system encoding, or otherwise. I can gladly follow up details.

Answer (score 1):

`format()` will sometimes fail this way when some variables you are passing it as arguments contain non-ascii characters, while the base string is ascii.

Regarding why it would run on OSX and not Linux, well each OS has a specific way to handle characters encoding, which can lead to this kind of problem.

Try this:

```
"your sting {} ".encode('utf-8').format(.....
```

Comment: Thanks. I do `.encode('utf-8') on all strings, and it works on OSX's version, but now fails on Linxu. Default encoding is `ascii` on both. I'll investigate more.

Comment: try also encoding the vars you give to format, may do the trick. (varName and content)